# How do I get the name of the creative through the adcreativev2 API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to find the API that lets me query for the creative name through the creative ID. When I used this API: [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2/{creative](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2/%7Bcreative) id}
It returned the information of the creative but the name is missing.

Answer (score 0):

So basically after exploring endlessly the doc and available forums, it seems a name can be found using the API [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adDirectSponsoredContents/{URN}](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adDirectSponsoredContents/%7BURN%7D)
where the URN can be found in the original  [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2/{creative](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2/%7Bcreative) id}. It if the value of the field reference.

It seems unintuitive to have it in a separate endpoint instead of the original GET api. Hope it helps anyone who stumbles on this answer.

P.S Sometimes the API will return a 404 response to a perfectly existing ad, I don't know the cause exactly but when you view the ad on the campaign manager you will see that the creative name will have the value of the creative ID.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct on how to get the creative names through the adCreativeV2 API. HOWEVER, this is literally being deprecated in about a week (2/28).

By the 28th, you have to migrate to the "versioned" LinkedIn API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/versioning?view=li-lm

The adCreativesV2 endpoint will fail. I still have no idea how to grab the creative names on the versioned API. I've reached out to LinkedIn.

Here are some of the changes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/versioning?view=li-lms-2023-02

I haven't been able to use the new creatives endpoint to get the creative name.  It's even less precise than their old API, and since the share endpoints are being deprecated, I'm not sure where to go.

I'll update you if I hear back. Their API is frustrating and very poorly documented.

**EDIT**: You're getting 404s on some ads probably because those ads are NOT DSC. There are unfortunately multiple different endpoints you have to call to expose the creative contents depending on the ad type and if it's DSC or not. But as mentioned, this is all being deprecated in about a week, so I don't think it's worth implementing since it'll all break on the 28th when the old V2 endpoints are deprecated.

Comment: Hey thanks for the update, from what I gathered from the linked docs, the API will not fail at the end of the month strictly, but rather when they "sunset" in 9 months right? In addition, it seems they listed the plans of having a new version but not the exact changelog for the API.

Comment: Hey, no problem. My understanding was the 9 month window started June 2022, and it's being fully sunset next week, February 28th, 2023. 

This is from an email I've received earlier this month from LinkedIn:

[Deadline Imminent] Migrate to versioned APIs and new Content APIs by February 28, 2023

In June 2022, we introduced API Versioning and new Content APIs to make it easier for you to build with ease and manage API changes with predictability. With the new APIs, we plan to sunset the unversioned APIs and legacy Content APIs (Shares API, UGC API) on February 28, 2023.

Comment: After looking further into it you are right. Have you been able to discover the versioned way of using the https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adDirectSponsoredContents/ API? The documentation does not provide an alternative.